# PyRun_SimpleString fails for def foo():

Tags: c++, python, python-embedding

I could not get PyRun_SimpleFile to work (FILE* compatibility issue) for files that have unicode (widechar) in their name/path and hence this question!

So, I decided to open the python script myself & then execute each line using PyRun_SimpleString.

Pseudo code shown here.

```
wchar_t* pWScriptName=NULL;
// pWScriptName malloced & populated here
FILE* fp = _wfopen(pWScriptName, L"r");
while (fgets(line, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL) {
    int ret = PyRun_SimpleString(line);
    if(ret != 0) {
        ... error at lineNum ...
    }
    lineNum++;
}
```

Above gives error at the def statement below (<-- shown below)

Python version is 2.7

```
import os
print "hello"
def foo():  # <-- PyRun_SimpleString fails here
    print "hello again"
```

I would like to use this to show the line number of the script where if/it fails. Many other people seem to be successful with PyRun_SimpleString!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PyRun_SimpleString expects a complete source-code string, not a single line from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't use PyRun_SimpleString in this case because it expects to read the entirety of the program in one line, you are breaking it into multiple lines.

You should just use `PyRun_SimpleFile(fileReference, scriptPath)`

Note: you'll need to create the globals and locals objects for the above to work.

[See this](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html)

Comment: Problem is PWScriptName is wchar_t*. I have updated the question. But as mentioned I am not able to get PyRun_SimpleFile working for file shaving wide-chars in their path/name.

Comment: You don't pass the wchar_t* in this case, you need to give it (fp, scriptPath)

Comment: I know. All PyRun APIs that take FILE* as an argument crash for me because the FILE structures of VC2010 and Python do not match. This is a well documented issue especially for windows.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer. Make a buffer of your entire script & pass it PyRun_SimpleString. Error detection is not possible in that case.